# Passing a function from an object to the component to edit the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, redux-form

I have a FIELDS object containing settings for many fields (also objects) that will be used to build the input fields in my page with the function renderField. Some of these fields need a function to edit the state of the component. I need this to be able to do some sort of autocompletion while the user is filling the form.

The code looks like this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Field,reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

// objects that will be used to create the form
const FIELDS = {
  first_name: {
    type: 'text',
    label: 'First name',
    onChange: function(e){
      this.setstate({first_name:e.target.value})
  },
  last_name: {
    type: 'text',
    label: 'last name',
    onChange: function(e){
      this.setstate({last_name:e.target.value})
  },
  ...
  }
  
  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        first_name : '',
        last_name : '',
        birth : '',
        sex:''
      };
    }
    
    renderField(field) {
      const fieldConfig = FIELDS[field.input.name];
      const {meta: {touched, error}} = field;

      return (
        <div className={`form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' :''}`}>
          <br />
          <label>{fieldConfig.label}</label>
          <input
            {...fieldConfig}
            {...field.input}
          />
          <div className='text-help'>{touched ? error : ""}</div>
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    }

    onSubmit(){
        ...
    }

    render() {
      const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
            { _.keys(FIELDS).map( key => {
              return <Field name={key} key={key} component={this.renderField} />;
              })
            }

          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  // validate,
  form: 'Form example'
})(
  connect(null)(App)
);
```

I know that I can't call this.setState() this way, but I have no idea how I could bind the function inside the object inside the component. I did a lot of research and can't seem to find a solution. I don't know if it's because I'm not following good practices or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Judging by your imports, you're trying to use Redux in this project. If so, you need to use actions and reducers to set your Redux state, not `setState()` and local state (in general). If you haven't already, read this: http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am going to use redux in my project, but I wasn't sure if putting these values in the application state was good because these are only going to be used inside this component. I need these values to autofill one of the fields in the form so the user only needs to fill a small part of this field. Even if I used redux, I'm not sure how I could access the actions by putting this.props.actionName inside the objects "first_name" and "last_name"

Comment: I don't get how the internal component state is supposed to help with autocompletion. That internal state would just store the exact same value that Redux-form is already storing for you. If already know the value of some of the fields, then you can initialize form fields from the Redux state, using the technique shown here https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/initializefromstate/

Comment: One of the fields will be a code that contains the following: first 3 letters of the last name, the first letter of the first name, the date of birth (YYMMDD,MM+50 if female), and 2 random numbers. For example: John Smith (01-10-1987) will be SMIJ871001 with 2 numbers at the end that the user has to enter. I want to autofill the known part of the code while the user is entering the information so he only has to fill the last 2 numbers. I have no way to know what they are, explaining why I need the user's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of doing something complicated I just moved the function from the object directly in the render function in the component, making the connection to the state possible.